# Initialising const Array at Struct in C

Tags: c, embedded

The code snippet:

```
static struct
{
     static const unsigned char myConstArray[] =
     {
           50, 51, 52, 52, 53, 54, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58, 58, 59, 60,
     };

     //more....
 }_SomeValues;
```

How could this work? (complains that after = a ; is missing)

Comment: Plain C can't have static members in a struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change to:

```
static struct
{
     const unsigned char myConstArray[14];

} _SomeValues =
    {
        {
           50, 51, 52, 52, 53, 54, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58, 58, 59, 60,
        }
    };
```

Comment: the real one is a bit bigger: {{{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},0,{0,0},{50, 51, 52, 52, 53, 54, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93,  94,  95,  96,  98,  99, 100, 102, 103,  105, 106, 108, 109, 111, 112, 114, 115, 117, 118, 120, 122, 123, 125, 127, 129, 130, 132, 134, 136, 137, 139, 141, 143, 145,},};

Answer (score 1):

you cant have static variables in struct

Comment: That doesn't compile with gcc.

Comment: As a side note, trailing comma is allowed in enums but not in structs. This is an obscure C99/C11 feature.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the links below might help you as well

[Static Const Initialised Structure Array in C++ Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605058/static-const-initialised-structure-array-in-c-class)

[c++ Initializing a struct with an array as a member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650374/c-initializing-a-struct-with-an-array-as-a-member)